# How do you store a user input after calling a void function in C?

Tags: c

Issue: I am writing this program which allows users to enter their name and school details via fgets() method in a void function after being called from the int function, how do i make sure that the array in this void function is a global array which then allows me to call another function called list users that lists all the user details?

```
int main(){

int choice, userEnd =1;
printf("1: list user details\n");
printf("2: add user details \n");
printf("3: end the programme\n");

while(userEnd)
{
    printf("Enter your choice: \n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if(choice==1){
        listUsers();
    }
    if(choice ==2){
        addUsers();
    }
    if(choice ==3){
        userEnd =0;
    }
    
}
return 0;
}

void addUsers(){
    int length = 100;
    char userName[length];
    char className[length];
  
    printf("Enter user name\n");
    fgets(userName,size,stdin);
    printf("Enter className:\n");
    fgets(className,size,stdin);
    printf("User added\n");
    
}

void listUsers(){

/*if addUsers array is empty, print "empty", else print all user details from addUsers.*/
printf("your name is %s, your class is %s",userName, userSize)

}
```

Comment: Don't declare the variables in the function scope, but outside all of the functions. Those variables are in the global scope and are accessible by the global name from all functions. It's better to use arguments and return values for this, but I guess you are still learning.

Comment: Declare the variable outside any function and it will be global in thaytfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a global array, you have to declare it outside the functions scope, so in your case:

```
/* global array, declared in the global scope */
array_type array[ELEMENTS];

int main () {

}

void addUsers () {

}

void listUsers () {

}
```

Using that setup you will be able to manipulate the array from every function.

But, as it has been said in the comments, you should not use global variables/arrays in this case. Instead, you should use return values and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will do!
Note that this code is still a non- working copy of what you want to do but with a few little touches, it should work fine.

```
/* Global vars */
const int length = 100;
char *userName[length]; // array of strings
char *className[length];

/* Keep track of number of users */
int userCount = 0;

int main(){

    int choice, userEnd =1;
    printf("1: list user details\n");
    printf("2: add user details \n");
    printf("3: end the programme\n");

    while(userEnd)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if(choice==1){
            listUsers();
        }
        if(choice ==2){
            addUsers();
            userCount++;
        }
        if(choice ==3){
            userEnd =0;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}

void addUsers(){
    // TODO: make sure userCount doesn't exceed the length
    // TODO: define size
    printf("Enter user name\n");
    fgets(userName[userCount],size,stdin);
    printf("Enter className:\n");
    fgets(className[userCount],size,stdin);
    printf("User added\n");
    
}

void listUsers(){
    int i;

    /*if addUsers array is empty, print "empty", else print all user details from addUsers.*/
    if (userCount > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0, i < userCount, i++)
        {
            printf("your name is %s, your class is %s",userName[i], className[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No users registered");
    }

}
```